# My AES function encrypts value correctly, but decrypting returns FALSE

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I have problem with mine AES encryption class. Here it is:

```php
<?php
require_once 'SecretData.php';

class AESEncryption
{
    private static $AES_METHOD = 'aes-256-cbc';

    public static function encrypt($data, $key = null)
    {
        if($key == null)
        {
            $secretData = new SecretData();
            $key = $secretData->universalAESKey;
        }

        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$AES_METHOD);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivSize);

        $encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, self::$AES_METHOD, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv . $encryptedData);
    }

    public static function decrypt($data, $key = null)
    {
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        if($key == null)
        {
            $secretData = new SecretData();
            $key = $secretData->universalAESKey;
        }

        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$AES_METHOD);
        $iv = mb_substr($data, 0, $ivSize, '8bit');
        $decryptedData = mb_substr($data, $ivSize, null, '8bit');

        return openssl_decrypt($decryptedData, self::$AES_METHOD, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
}
```

Something in my login class was wrong, and I caught that this function is cause of errors. I made following debug file:

```php
<?php
require_once '/var/www/backend/security/HashingAlgorithms.php';
require_once '/var/www/backend/security/AESEncryption.php';

$data = 'alpha';

$enc = AESEncryption::encrypt($data);
$dec = AESEncryption::decrypt($enc);

echo 'Input: ' . $data . ' <> Encrypted: ' . $enc . ' <> Decrypted: ' . $dec;
var_dump($dec);
```

This is an output:

```
Input: alpha <> Encrypted: 7hB1hNiSYvU+Hy4xgvHb2sf/cVa2NPkx4+3kX+qdvUM= <> Decrypted: bool(false)
```

When I looked at the code, everthing looks fine:

- I get key from SecretData function (secret key is 100% correct),
- Get IV length and generate it,
- OpenSSL encrypts data and I use base64 to store IV and encrypted value.

Same I did with decrypt function:

- Decode from base64,
- Get IV length and divide base64 decoded data to IV itself and encrypted data
- OpenSSL decrypt data and return value.

Can anyone look at this and tell me what is wrong

Comment: You can modify this working example. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/x9kj/string-encryption-and-decryption-with-openssl-in-php

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem [here](https://paiza.io/projects/Rqs8i9OJgl1E9QXM3e7ydg) (using my own key because `SecretData` wasn't posted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the `SecretData.php` file, I cannot direct you to a specific point of failure. However, I can just create one dummy myself to confirm that the code itself works fine.

**Code**

```php
<?php

class SecretData
{
    public $universalAESKey = '79f0f1a2e72b6654bba3071ff8210c13';
}

class AESEncryption
{
    private static $AES_METHOD = 'aes-256-cbc';

    public static function encrypt($data, $key = null)
    {
        if($key == null)
        {
            $secretData = new SecretData();
            $key = $secretData->universalAESKey;
        }

        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$AES_METHOD);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivSize);

        $encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, self::$AES_METHOD, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv . $encryptedData);
    }

    public static function decrypt($data, $key = null)
    {
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        if($key == null)
        {
            $secretData = new SecretData();
            $key = $secretData->universalAESKey;
        }

        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$AES_METHOD);
        $iv = mb_substr($data, 0, $ivSize, '8bit');
        $decryptedData = mb_substr($data, $ivSize, null, '8bit');

        return openssl_decrypt($decryptedData, self::$AES_METHOD, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```php
$data = 'alpha';

$enc = AESEncryption::encrypt($data);
$dec = AESEncryption::decrypt($enc);

echo 'INPUT:' . $data . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ENCRP:' . $enc . PHP_EOL;
echo 'DECRP:' . $dec . PHP_EOL;

$enc = AESEncryption::encrypt($data, "e2e0cc36ea14bc5cd94473facd4731a6");
$dec = AESEncryption::decrypt($enc, "e2e0cc36ea14bc5cd94473facd4731a6");

echo 'INPUT:' . $data . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ENCRP:' . $enc . PHP_EOL;
echo 'DECRP:' . $dec . PHP_EOL;
```

**Result**

```sh
INPUT:alpha
ENCRP:PUn1xaDRMX4U0K4NVnJiRv4mtROpn3WvcFnSrR9EJ98=
DECRP:alpha

INPUT:alpha
ENCRP:QOs1vvy/6aKRSVGmZQWp7EvSNoISCpJ4Vsy3T3ixXZ4=
DECRP:alpha
```

Comment: So... why my code was not working? That one is identical to mine listed above and after copy & paste of your code all is working...
(I used my original SecretData.php)

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the app, setup, etc. Guessing that there is no caching going on somewhere in your app, there was probably something minor somewhere in your code. I cannot tell much to be honest.